# How to load images into the ListView from DateBase?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I am filling in my `listview` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.
By using `getView()` I set the image to an `imageView` for each item.

Now I only have 1 image (in the first row) in my `cursor`. But on scroll it appears in random positions. Why it is so?

**code**

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    private Cursor cur;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public MyListAdapter (Context context, Cursor c, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, c, new String[] {}, new int[] {}); 
        this.cur=super.getCursor();
        this.context = context;
        this.db=db;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle, txtDate;
        ImageView imgSm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            holder.imgSm= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_sm);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
          } 
          else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

        this.cur.moveToPosition(position);  

        holder.txtTitle.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex("title")));
        holder.txtDate.setText(this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex("date")));

        byte[] blob = this.cur.getBlob(this.cur.getColumnIndex("img_sm"));
        if (blob!=null) {
            holder.imgSm.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: if blob is null use `imgSm.setImageBitmap(null);` edit: it will not work try `imgSm.setImageResource(0);`(if blob is null)

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!!!)
Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: here you go with more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it becouse ListView recycling ...
ListView creating only visible items + few more.
if you scroll invisible items will be reused if they are no longer visible.
you setting only first image(as you said that only first row in cursor has blob data)
so if first row is resused you get a row with image allready setup to fist one.

so use

```
        if (blob!=null) {
            holder.imgSm.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length));
        }else{
           holder.imgSm.setImageResource(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your ListView basicly doesnt know which image it's rendering and when you are scrolling up and down it's refreshing itself and redrawing the image randomly.
You need to keep track of which image belong to which ListView Item you can achieve this 
by using the position.

Comment: Why does Listview understand to which row `this.cur.getString(this.cur.getColumnIndex("..."))` belong and `this.cur.getBlob(this.cur.getColumnIndex("img_sm"))` - not?